# Стирание span inline-block как текста (backspace) в div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, вёрстка

Имеем редактируемый div, в котором в произвольных местах текста может расположить inline-block элементы, в chrome всё хорошо, а вот в том же firefox при стирании backspace курсор стопорится (или плодит отступы) и элемент не стирает ...
Была попытка обрабатывать сам backspace, но Range толковой информации не даёт ...

```css
.content {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  transition: border .2s;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #2475FF ;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tag_container {
  font-size: 5px;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .tag_conteiner {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
  Какойтотекст<span  contenteditable="false" class="tag_container">&nbsp;<span contenteditable="false" class="tag">Куку</span>&nbsp;</span>ЭтотTекстCтереть (backspace)
</div>
```

Поиграться еще можно тут: http://jsfiddle.net/u04k2xp1/

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685445 // а зачем вы вставляете contenteditable=false внутри contenteditable=true?

Comment: Что бы содержание элементов с параметром contenteditable=false нельзя было редактировать.

Answer (score 2):

Известный [баг](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=685445) в Firefox. Посмотрите англоязычные ответы на подобный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177958/2452094 — там как раз есть варианты с обработкой клавиши Backspace в Javascript.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.